# View Pager show only 1 ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I'm building some custom listview then add them to View Pager.
But when I swift screen, View Pager show only 1 Custom ListView.

this is the image of problem:
[image]

the SpeakingActivity.java

```
public class SpeakingActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    static final int    NUM_ITEMS   = 4;
    MyAdapter           mAdapter;
    ViewPager           mPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_Sherlock); // Used for theme switching in samples
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_pager);
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    public class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        SpeakingFragment    myFrag[];
        int                 numItem = 4;

        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            myFrag = new SpeakingFragment[numItem];
            for(int i = 0; i < numItem; i++) {
                myFrag[i] = new SpeakingFragment();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount(){
            return numItem;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position){
            return myFrag[position];
        }
    }
```

the SpeakingFragment.java

```
public class SpeakingFragment extends SherlockFragment {
    public final String                     KEY_SONG            = "song";
    public final String                     KEY_ID          = "id";
    public final static String              KEY_TITLE       = "title";
    public final static String              KEY_ARTIST      = "artist";
    public final static String              KEY_DURATION    = "duration";
    public final static String              KEY_THUMB_URL   = "thumb_url";
    ListView                                        list;
    LazyAdapter                                 adapter;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>  songsList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        list = (ListView) getSherlockActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);
        songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put(KEY_ID, String.valueOf(i));
            map.put(KEY_TITLE, "Title" + i);
            map.put(KEY_ARTIST, "Dolphin");
            map.put(KEY_DURATION, "11:11");
            map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, "Thumb");
            songsList.add(map);
        }
        adapter = new LazyAdapter(getSherlockActivity(), songsList);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
            }
        });
    }
}
```

LazyAdapter.java

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity                                        activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>  data;
    private LayoutInflater                              inflater    = null;
    public ImageLoader                                  imageLoader;

    public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data = d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount(){
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position){
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position){
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View vi = convertView;
        if(convertView == null) vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
        TextView title = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.title); // title
        TextView artist = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.artist); // artist name
        TextView duration = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.duration); // duration
        ImageView thumb_image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image
        HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
        song = data.get(position);
        title.setText(song.get(SpeakingFragment.KEY_TITLE));
        artist.setText(song.get(SpeakingFragment.KEY_ARTIST));
        duration.setText(song.get(SpeakingFragment.KEY_DURATION));
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(SpeakingFragment.KEY_THUMB_URL), thumb_image);
        return vi;
    }
}
```

You can try full code [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kx5kgnjdw0b1a8l/ListViewOnPagers.rar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the error my self.
The swift action ocur before onActivityCreated.  It makes the next fragment isn't show up but when swift back, onActivityCreated occured so it appear.
to fix this error, change the code from onActivityCreated to onCreateView (because onCreateView occur before swift).